Passive Construction - Standard Form vs. Non-Standard Form
I've encountered a sentence in a formal e-mail about shipping a product.

The company will be shipped a new product.

I couldn't comprehend it at first glance. I though it should be like:

A new product will be shipped to the company.

I think the original sentence is missing "to" preposition and that's why it feels a little awkward. But I'm not a native English speaker. So if you could help me to understand this, I would appreciate it.

Where would you put that "to"? In this sentence, as it stands, I see no place where to insert this preposition.

Actually, I can’t put it anywhere. I just thought hypothetically that "to" might solve the issue, but I agree with you. There is no place to put "to" or maybe at the end of the sentence?

No, adding "to" at the end  would not make a correct sentence.

Contrast the ergative usage of shipped: 'Your order has shipped.'

This seems perfectly idiomatic to me. Should this question be migrated to [ell.se]?

The company will be shipped a new product. -> A new product will be shipped to the company

The sentence is completely OK. "The company will be shipped" alone seems like the company is being shipped, but if combined with the rest of the sentence it is OK; i.e., "will be shipped a new product" just simply means that a new product will be shipped.

This is correct.
For ditransitive verbs, there are two ways of using the active voice:

The factory shipped a new product to the company.
The factory shipped the company a new product.

In the passive, these become:

A new product was shipped to the company by the factory.
The company was shipped a new product by the factory.

Which you choose depends on a number of subtle details, including what thing you want to emphasize.

Modern English is somewhat unique in allowing the indirect object of a ditransitive verb to become the subject if that verb is made passive. It can be unintuitive because that indirect object used to be a dative, before the formal case distinctions began to disappear.
So, in Modern English, the active he gave her a gift usually becomes the passive she was given a gift (by him).
In older English, it would have become a gift was given her (by him). The two forms competed for a while before the modern one won out, although the older one still appears from time to time in academic and legal language, for example. This older form is the norm in most other Indo-European languages; English is the oddity.
Perhaps interestingly, in Latin, verbs that take both a dative and an accusative allow only the accusative to be made the subject in a passive sentence. But verbs that take a so-called double accusative allow either accusative to become the subject. Perhaps, as the English case system wore away, the original dative and accusative were reanalyzed like a double accusative, with both objects seeming to have even footing, so that either one could be made subject.
This answer is mostly written on the off chance that you’re a non-native speaker unfamiliar with English ditransitive verbs. Perhaps for such a person historical and cross-linguistic examples may be useful.

Double transitive verbs can be used in the passive voice.

—  John will teach Jane a lesson.  [They will ship the company a new product. ] (If "ship" was double transitive, this would be the acctive voice form (you have to supply a subject (they), which, being the agent in the passive construction, can be suppressed, and has been suppressed in the OP's passive form.)
— Jane will be taught a lesson by John. [The companhy  will be shipped a new product (by them).]

The problem is that "ship" is nowhere defined as a double transitive verb, but there is in fact a practice of using "ship" as a double transitive.
Copilot
shipped him some
Consequently, this could be a correct sentence or tend to be correct.
But Copilot says it is not; "ship" is double transitive when a pronoun is used for the first object.

Sent by Copilot :
The verb “ship” can indeed take two objects, but there’s a nuance in how it’s used. When “ship” is used with double objects, one of them is typically a pronoun. For example:
“They shipped me the package.”
“She shipped him the documents.”
In these sentences, “me” and “him” are indirect object pronouns, while “the package” and “the documents” are direct objects.
However, when both objects are nouns, the structure changes, and “ship” is usually followed by a preposition to clarify the relationship between the objects:
“They shipped the package to the customer.”
“She shipped the documents to the office.”
In these cases, “the package” and “the documents” are direct objects, and “to the customer” and “to the office” are prepositional phrases indicating the indirect objects.


That makes sense. I was trying to figure out why ship sounded terrible, send sounded off, but give sounded fine.

@PhilSweet Various other verbs have the same awkwardness that ship has in this way.  You can book someone a room but you can't say that the room was booked him.

'They shipped the bureau the bureau' sounds really outlandish.

@tchrist "*the room was booked him" - Isn't that wrong because you're not using the passive voice? "He was booked a room" is perfectly fine.

@wjandrea There is not a single hit in Google ngrams for "was booked a room", so it can't be used too often.

@LPH I never said it's attested, just that it's correct. There are also no hits on Ngrams for "There is not a single hit".

@wjandrea There is difference: a room being booked is happening of everyday life that is very likely to be mentioned in all sorts of contexts, whereas the hits from a Google search are not at all like that.

@LPH There are also no hits for "all our rooms have been booked"

@wjandrea No doubt, this is heard often enough. (Don't forget the normal ngram search is limited to 5 words, though)

I wouldn't cite Copilot here because it's not a reliable source for this sort of relatively complex question about grammar.

@alphabet Yet, their answer corresponds acurately to facts: 1) absence of the double transitive aspect in dictionaries, 2) the occurrence of double transitivity for two pronouns as shown in Google searches, and 3) the impression of oddness of several readers. It is quite surprising.

@LPH But Copilot is wrong that either of the objects can be a noun as long as the other is a pronoun; "I shipped the man it" sounds wrong. (This is related to a more general fact about how syntactic weight influences the choice of ditransitive over monotransitive constructions.)

@alphabet What it said in the explanation I obtained is that when ditransitive, this verb is used with a pronoun; it does not say that the pronoun can be used anywhere, and in the examples this machine provides, although there are but two, neither  of the two is of the sort you show (which sounds definitely incorrect to me too).  I agree that more specificity would be a plus. Maybe you  asked Copilot the same question and you obtained something different, but that is another matter.
